# How to create an automatically updating alphabetical list of unique occurrences in a range of cells?

Tags: worksheet-function, macros, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, google-spreadsheets

To illustrate, let's say we have a range of `'sheet1'!$B$2:$F$8` that looks like:

```
Dennis   Charlie    Frank    Dennis    Aaron
Charlie  Frank      Erik     Aaron     Charlie
Aaron    Dennis     Charlie  Charlie   Dennis
Bill                Aaron              Hank
                    Hank
                    Dennis
                    Bill
```

...wherein each column is a separate person's ranking of preference among various possible choices.

The goal here is to create a list of all unique ranked choices and put them into single column on a different sheet, ideally in alphabetical order (so `A1` on `sheet2` would be "Aaron", `'sheet2'!A2` would be "Bill", &c).

The pool of all available choices changes regularly and includes dozens of possible choices that ultimately won't be ranked, and the rankings themselves change often as well (including who is/isn't ranked), so this list needs to be generated using (and automatically update from) the above range to avoid wasting time manually updating it and wasting space on unranked choices.

Any idea how to go about doing this?

## Edit: Partial solution found:

After a lot of searching around I found [this Google Docs Help Forum post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/docs/how-do-i/HVapsmoHONw) and was able to adapt it to do what I want it to in Google Sheets by putting the following formula into `A1` on `sheet2`:

```
 =sort(unique(transpose(split(ArrayFormula(concatenate(Sheet1!B2:F&"|")),"|"))))
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work in my preferred software (LibreOffice Calc) and I have no idea how to use macros to make it work, but if nobody can help with that this will work as a temporary fix.

Comment: It's definitely not a good idea to do it with worksheet functions, you need to use macros.

Comment: Never worked with macros before so I really don't know where to start with that, but I did find a partial solution (works in Google Sheets only) and have edited my question to include it.

Comment: You need to delete the tag "microsoft-excel" because they don't pertain the your question. You are using Libre Office and Google which don't match the capabilities of MS Excel.